# Writing 4:2:0 YUV-Rawdata into an AVI-File via Video for Windows in C++

Tags: c++, video, avi

I'm trying to write some 4:2:0 rawdata received from a capture card into an AVI-File. For every pixel the char buffer contains 2 Bytes (16 Bit). The order of the data is the same as FOURCC UYVY: YUV 4:2:2 (Y sample at every pixel, U and V sampled at every second pixel horizontally on each line). A macropixel contains 2 pixels in 1 u_int32.

First I tried the OpenCV Videowriter. But this is simply slow for this huge amount of video data (I'm capturing 2 video streams, each is 1080p25 format), so I switched to the "Video for Windows"-Library by Windows. My C++ - algorithm contains the following source code:

First I initialise the AVIFile avi_left & AVIStream avi_left_s:

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    AVIFileInit();

    hr=AVIFileOpen(&avi_left,L"Test.avi",OF_WRITE|OF_CREATE, NULL);


    if (hr != 0)
    {
        printf("AVI ERROR");
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(0);
    }

    //No compression output with 25 fps

    al_info.fccType                = streamtypeVIDEO;    
    al_info.fccHandler             = 0;                 
    al_info.dwScale                = 1;                                       
    al_info.dwRate                 = 25; 
    al_info.dwSuggestedBufferSize  = 0;
    al_info.dwSampleSize = 0;
    SetRect( &al_info.rcFrame, 0, 0,1920,1080);

    //Define Header for the YUV-Rawdata

    BITMAPINFO bi; 
    ZeroMemory(&bi,sizeof(bi)); 
    BITMAPINFOHEADER &bmi = bi.bmiHeader;

    bmi.biSize=sizeof(bmi);
    bmi.biWidth=1920;
    bmi.biHeight=1080;
    bmi.biPlanes=1;
    bmi.biBitCount=16;
    bmi.biCompression=0x59565955;
    bmi.biSizeImage = bmi.biWidth*bmi.biHeight*2;
    bmi.biXPelsPerMeter=10000;
    bmi.biYPelsPerMeter=10000;
    bmi.biClrUsed=0;
    bmi.biClrImportant=0;


    hr = AVIFileCreateStream(avi_left,&avi_left_s,&al_info);
    hr = AVIStreamSetFormat(avi_left_s, 0,&bmi,sizeof(bmi));
```

If some new Data is arriving:

```
//m_byteBufferleft = rawdata as char array in UYVY-order

            BYTE* bufferleft=(BYTE*)m_byteBufferleft;


    // Writing Data

            long size = width * height * 2;
            HRESULT hr = AVIStreamWrite(avi_left_s,frameCount-1,1,bufferleft,size,AVIIF_KEYFRAME,NULL,NULL);
```

If Capturing has ended:

```
//Closing AVIStream & AVIFile

AVIStreamClose(avi_left_s);
AVIFileClose(avi_left);
AVIFileExit();
```

But this code doesn't works fine. While the last part is running I receive the error message: Unbehandelte Ausnahme bei 0x5ee36266 in XsensDecklinkCapture.exe: 0xC0000005: Zugriffsverletzung beim Lesen an Position 0xcdcdcdcd. Maybe you have any ideas? Are there any big mistakes in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Before even checking the video code per se, as soon you have access violation exception you should address this problem directly. You have exception - you can check call stack at exception position, and you should post it here to provide the code line which causes the problem.

With `0xcdcdcdcd` you are likely to have a problem with an uninitialized pointer being accessed as if it is valid.

Comment: Sorry my fault ;) Finally got it, the code works fine ;) Regards

Comment: Actually it's also very slow maybe you got some ideas to speed it up?

Comment: If anything is slow, it is not the code you have posted in the original question. `AVI` API is extremely lightweight. It was built 15+ years ago when video processing created huge load onto workstations, and API already worked nice at that time. You have slow stuff elsewhere, so you will need to isolate these processing stages in the course of debugging.

Comment: Hey, I trow everything out of my Code beside the above and the receiving of the frames. I know that my capturing device is able to deliver both raw data buffers within 40 ms. So this can't be the reason for Framerates below 10 fps. Are you shure that there are no problems by writing 2 streams? Or maybe the 1080p video format is to large for streaming in realtime? Sorry I've no other ideas, thx a lot for your help.

Comment: Are you writing dual 1920x1080 12 bits per pixel 10 fps into a file? This is 60 megabytes per second, you might be just hitting your HDD writing capacity limit.

Comment: Sometimes simple solutions are the best ^^. Thx a lot. Using a RAID solves the problem. Regards

Comment: Sorry, still one more problem to solve. The file fize doesn't exceeds 4GB. And if the AVI is >2GB I can't watch it. Is this caused in the use of Video for Windows and is there the possibility to change the Header to AVI 2.0 to fix this? Just for Information: I'm using NTFS.

Comment: You are unlikely to fix this. Large AVIs are problematic. I don't remember off the cuff for sure, but I am under impression AVI Mux is itself incapable to write the large flies. Your choices are to (a) use a different mux, if you fnid one (b) use another container format, or (c) use custom renderer to write frames into separate files - which is perhaps a bit complex if you are not familiar with filters, but perhaps the best if you need the data exactly ucompressed and you will do some processing in another app (separate files might have plain format).

Comment: Ok seems like I have to use DirectShow. There is no possibility to fix this while using Video for Windows without DirectShow as the code above? Thanks for your hints!